# Error with jars in maven: 'sudo mvn package' has errors, but 'mvn package' does not; neither function properly

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven

I have manually installed the jars I need in the local repository using `mvn install:install-file`. If I type `sudo mvn package`, two of the jars give this error:

> [WARNING] The POM for org.openid4java:openid4java-full:jar:0.9.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
>
> [WARNING] The POM for mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.31 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

Then later...

> [ERROR] error: error reading /var/root/.m2/repository/org/openid4java/openid4java-full/0.9.5/openid4java-full-0.9.5.jar; error in opening zip file
>
> [ERROR] error: error reading /var/root/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.31/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar; error in opening zip file

However, if I use `mvn package` (no `sudo`), then it compiles without errors, but does not function properly.

The code is working just fine on a collaborator's machine, so the `pom`s must be fine. I assume that there is something wrong with my setup. (He is using Eclipse and I am using command line and text editor)

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo mvn install:install-file`

then `sudo mvn package`

Answer (score 0):

Why have you use the sudo function with mvn ?

Using sudo, you risk to add file with incorrect right on it.

In your case, i will try to verify the right on this two file to obtain the same behavior with and without using sudo ...

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The permissions on these jars are the same as all the other jars in the repository. Dheerendra Kulkami suggested installing the jars using sudo, but that also makes no difference.